# DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message (discord.js v12)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to get the `message.content` of messages being sent in a channel. When the message is sent, I am given an error:

> DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Code:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {

    if (message.channel.id === "CHANNELID") {

      const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setDescription(message.content)
      .setColor("#E74C3C")
      .setTimestamp()
      .setAuthor(message.author.tag, message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))

      message.client.channels.cache.get(CHANNELID).send(embed);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure this is v12? Is this your full code in this event?

Comment: This is v12, not v13 and this is my full code in the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your send...

```
message.client.channels.cache.get(CHANNELID).send(embed);
```

becomes

```
message.client.channels.cache.get(CHANNELID).send({embed});
```